# CA Certificate files get randomly updated

Tags: ssl-certificate, certificate

Is there some automated process that periodically updates the modify time on CA Certificates?  Our File Integrity Manager is alerting on files beneath /etc/certs/.  How are those files maintained?  This is happening on Red Hat 7.9 and later and on our Solaris 10 and 11 boxes.  It happens on a near-daily basis.  Is this normal?  Or have we been pwned?

Added information:

I'm reasonably certain it isn't malicious, but I not being able to explain the changes to security and cryptography files is awkward around audit time.  Some samples:

On Solaris

```
/etc/certs/ca-certificates.crt
/etc/openssl/certs/40193066.0
/etc/certs/CA/127.0.0.1.OpsCenter_cert.pem
```

On RHEL:

```
/etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/java/cacerts
/etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/pem/objsign-ca-bundle.pem
```

Comment: By default RHEL 7 stores  SSL/TLS/CA certificates in `/etc/pki` https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/security_guide/sec-shared-system-certificates and IIRC doesn't use `/etc/certs`. But without checking the contents of the /etc/certs and whatever additional software you have installed I wouldn't say that the presence of `/etc/certs` is malicious

Comment: According to Google, you probably have Oracle Ops Manager installed. I'd check their documentation.

You can always open up those .pems and examine the certs inside.

Comment: This probably shouldn't be tagged `ad-certificate-services`, which is about Active Directory CA services

Comment: @LeeM, thanks.  Deleted that tag.